# Update "updated" property every time a property has been changed

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

My doctrine entity has a `datetime` property called `updated`. This should get the current time everytime (changed) values of the object are written to the DB. I know how to do this in MySql, but I'm looking for a doctrine/symfony solution.

Is there a way to

1. hook into something before an INSERT/UPDATE of an instance is sent to the DB.
2. update the `updated` property to the current time and make sure it's written to the DB without triggering a second UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any extensions, just use [Lifecycle Callbacks](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks).
Basically, mark your entity that it has event callbacks configured with the `HasLifecycleCallbacks` annotation:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * ...
 */
class MyEntityClass {
...
```

And then mark instance methods to be run on specific events occuring, e.g. to set `updated`:

```
...
class MyEntityClass {
...
    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function onPreUpdate() {
        $this->updated = new \DateTime();
    }
...
```

Answer (score 5):

See the [Timestampable behavior](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md) of [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions). There is [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) to intergrate it into Symfony.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promissing as well.